# Massive delete and insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to create a script that checks if a register exists, if it does, it deletes it and inserts a new one with updated data.
I create the script with a program that copies a file from one NAS to another, and it's pretty basic.

So far my code creates a script with these lines:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 iDRegister FROM Documents WHERE iDRegister= 123456) BEGIN
    DELETE FROM Documents WHERE iDRegister= 123456
END
INSERT INTO Documents (iDRegister, idAPP, idDocType, Batch, BatchUploadDate, UploadDate, Route, idNas, Memo, NroMemo, DocID, ClientID, Folio, PolicyNum, CardNum, ProposalNum, RequirementNum, SolicitacionNum, AuditNum, RejectNum, SentMemo, OccurNum, StampDate, CompanyFund, IsMemo)
VALUES (123456, 10, 1, '1', CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), GETDATE(), 120), '20190416', 'Route\image.TIF', 1, '11111', '', '111111111', '', '11111111111111', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'NO')
```

This works perfectly, but I have to do the same for 2.2 million registers. Is there any way I can delete the previous register if it exists and then use bulk insert?

Answer (score 1):

Can you `UPDATE` instead?

```
UPDATE D
SET D.Field = D.NewValue
FROM Documents D
JOIN tableWithIDsToUpdate T ON D.iDRegister = T.iDRegister
```

You may still want to batch out the updates so you aren't doing 2.2 million at once though.

**Edit**

Since you need to also `INSERT` rows that don't exist to be updated, you can follow the above with this:

```
INSERT INTO Documents (col1, col2, etc)
SELECT col1, col2, etc
FROM tableWithIDsToUpdate T
LEFT JOIN Documents D ON D.iDRegister = T.idRegister
WHERE D.idRegister IS NULL
```

Comment: Due to the nature of the project I'm doing, I can't really afford the time to update them on small batches at a time. Also, not all registers exist, that's why to make it generic I put the condition that if exists, I delete it, otherwise I just insert it

Comment: @Throkar Why? You're essentially updating the record anyway. You're deleting it and inserting a new one. Not only will this be incredibly inefficient in changing a record, but it will grow your SQL logs tremendously.

Comment: Because I generate my script automatically on the program I can't really filter those who already have a register.

Comment: And OT, but two things that concern me. First, SQL 2005 is _ancient_. Ignoring the fact that the 4 versions of SQL Server after it are about to reach EOL, you'd see some significant performance improvements in upgrading to a more modern version. Second, I see a column `IsMemo` that is inserting a string. This seems like it should be a boolean, which would also improve your performance (and storage requirements).

Comment: I know SQL 2005 is pretty old, sadly, it's not really up to me to update it. As for the column IsMemo, it was already defined previously when I recieved the project.

Comment: @Shawn same with the date fields, stored as VARCHAR.

Comment: @Throkar That shouldn't make a difference. If you're already checking to see if a record exists. If it does, rather than `DELETE`, then `UPDATE`. Else, `INSERT`.

Comment: But is there a way to make it massive?

Comment: What do you mean by "massive"?

Comment: @Throkar While not intuitive, batching updates and inserts usually speeds up the total processing time.  Creating a 2.2 mil record large transaction is likely more burdensome than creating 11 200k record transactions.  That said, you know your system better than I do and if it can handle doing the full update/insert at once then go for it.

Comment: @Shawn, by massive I mean to ask if there's any way to make it so that I could insert/update maby 500k registers at a time.

Comment: To make this clear, you have a file on one NAS, you have some software application that sees that file, identifies it, and moves it to another NAS. Then creates a SQL command to be fired off to update a record in a database. Is that correct? What is the language you are using and how do you connect to your database to execute this SQL script?

Comment: @Throkar Are you looking to bulk move a lot of files? How often will this process run?

Comment: @Shawn, more or less, I'm using vb.net to create the application to copy the files from one NAS to another, I used to have stored procedures that did the insert into the database, but it made the process too slow. Now I'm looking to copy at least 500k at a time, if not more. My idea is to generate the script within the code and then execute it by hand.

Comment: I also have to update another database, and to do that I create a csv file with the code, bulk insert it into another table and then update. I was thinking on doing something similar with this insert (which is on another database on another server that's not linked to the first one)

Comment: If you're doing 500K individual INSERTs, it will beat up your db and your network pretty hard. If this is essentially a one-off, you may be able to script it out in such a way to minimize the pain as much as possible, but again, with SQL 2005, it's not going to be quick or easy. Will all 500k files have unique `idRegister`s? If not, I'd try to eliminate as many dupes as possible. You may be able to work with some temp tables to ease this move. Without knowing your system though, I don't think I can help too much. Your biggest pain will be actually moving those files.

Comment: Every idRegister is unique, my main issue is that there are some idRegisters that I'm trying to insert and they already exist, so I can't use a bulk insert. The moving part is already done, and I estimate around 13 hours to copy all 2.2 million files, but the way I have my script, the insert would take days, even if segmented in small portions.